# How to implement this using map and filter?

Tags: python

How to write a statement using `map` and `filter` to get same result as this list comprehension expression:

```
[(x,y) for x in range(10) if x%5==0
 for y in range(10) if y%5==1]
```

result:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 6), (5, 1), (5, 6)]
```

I know it seems to be pointless, but I'm just really curious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I did it without comprehesions:

```
sum(map(lambda x: map(lambda y: (x,y), filter(lambda y: y%5==1,range(10))), filter(lambda x: x%5==0,range(10))),[])
```

Executing:

```
>>> sum(map(lambda x: map(lambda y: (x,y), filter(lambda y: y%5==1,range(10))), filter(lambda x: x%5==0,range(10))),[])
[(0, 1), (0, 6), (5, 1), (5, 6)]
```

The last, and (maybe)nasty trick is using sum to flatten the list. I was getting **[[(0, 1), (0, 6)], [(5, 1), (5, 6)]]**.

Comment: I got a little eyes strain :).

Comment: Note that this sum 'trick' is a *really* bad idea in practice - it has to build every intermediate cumulative list, and ends up taking quadratic time. You can do the same in linear time and considerably less memory using itertools.chain: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(....))`.

Comment: Really, the original comprenhension is the best solution, but the challenge was to write it with python's built in functions.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the comments to one of the other answers, you want the cartesian product part of this - that is, this bit:

```
[(x,y) for x in range(10) for y in range(10)]
```

also done using just `map` and `filter`. This is impossible. The output of `map` has exactly as many elements as the iterable you input into it. The output of `filter` has length of *no more than* the length of the input. The length of a cartesian product is the product of the lengths of the inputs, which no combination of map and filter can give you.

To do the cartesian product part, you need some kind of nested loops. You can write them out yourself, as you have in the list comprehension, or you can use `itertools.product`:

```
product(range(10), range(10))
```

After that, you just need two applications of filter - to directly translate from a listcomp to map/filter, you need one application of filter for each if-part of the listcomp. The ifs are attached to each variable iteration rather than to the result, so you put them around each argument to product - which also avoids having to nest them creatively. Finally, we need to pass it through `list` since `product` gives an iterator.

It looks like this:

```
list(product(filter(lambda x: (x%5 == 0), range(10)), filter(lambda y: (y % 5 == 1), range(10))))
```